# Как решить проблему с ошибкой: Возникло исключение ImportError

Tags: python, исключения

Я начинающий программист и учусь подключать библиотеки.

Перед написанием кода, создал виртуальное окружение (выполниk команду pipenv shell) выбрал интерпретатор, а затем установил библиотеку (Pandas).

Написал вот такой код:

```
from panda import Template

templete = Templete("Hello, {{name}}!")
print(template.render(name="Harry"))
```

При запуске кода выходит ошибка:

Возникло исключение: ImportError
cannot import name 'Template' from partially initialized module 'panda' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\felix\Desktop\pandas_study\panda.py)
File "C:\Users\felix\Desktop\pandas_study\panda.py", line 1, in 
from panda import Template
File "C:\Users\felix\Desktop\pandas_study\panda.py", line 1, in 
from panda import Template

Пробовал менять интерпретаторы, удалял и создавал новый проект, искал синтаксические ошибки (не смог найти).

Фото кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Переименуй свой файл. И никогда не называй собственные файлы, как другие модули.

Comment: А также учись самостоятельно находить решения стандартных проблем. Здесь таких вопросов полторы сотни.

Comment: Так свой этот модуль `panda` тоже покажите

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка в ипорте

from panda import Templ**a**te

templete = Templ**e**te("Hello, {{name}}!")

Comment: Это уже другая ошибка.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло(

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка оказалась синтаксической:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это исправленный вид

Comment: Библиотека другую поставил.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.